# Laravel + Vue - CORS errors

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

I am developing a Laravel API + Vue.js frontend app. Those 2 projects are on separate servers. I am having a CORS policy problem in production (on local I had, but I managed to fix it).

So basically, there are 2 errors right now. I am having this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '--Laravel url--' from origin '--Vue url--' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

While my co-worker is getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '--Laravel url--' from origin '--Vue url--' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

We tried a few things:
Configurating CORS on Laravel side:

- setting CORS middleware - no effect
- changing CORS config .php file - no effect
  Configurating CORS on Vue side:
- adding origin header to form - no effect

The response is also displaying in browser as being same-site although it is not.

Anyone can help? We have been searching for answer for nearly 3 days.

Comment: Have you tried using Laravel Sanctum? It's specifically created for these scenarios: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: Hi yeah, we tried it. We have a different question for it now.

Comment: have you fixed this issue? it's also taking me days for this issue.

Comment: I went for sanctum, way easier to implement everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jazerix answered in a comment, going Sanctum is probably the right way because it has most stuff prepared.